# catkin configuration question

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros kinetic installed
I have projects that use rosmake
I have projects that use catkin_make
I have projects that use catkin build
I can not longer seem to get some of them to locate executable. I had them under a single directory under different src's
What is the proper structure for a system like this.  Since I added PTAM to src_nstd/src it can not  find executable s when using the launch file , keeps looking in src path and not devel.

My .bashrc file currently looks  like this:

```
   source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash 
   source /home/rjn/catkin_ws/src_nstd/setup.bash             # for rosmake
   source /home/rjn/catkin_ws/src_nstd/devel/setup.bash   # for catkin_make
   source /home/rjn/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash                 # for catkin build
```

catkin source structure looks like:

```
/home/rjn/catkin_ws/src_nstd/        # for rosmake -- does not use a src
/home/rjn/catkin_ws/src_nstd/src   # for catkin_make
/home/rjn/catkin_ws/src                 # for catkin build
```

I moved the catkin_make stuff to its own workspace.   I will do the same for rosmake.

But, Only the workspace build with catkin build a nd the kinetic installed launch files work. The ones built in catkin_make_ws exit with out giving an error. I can run them if I use rosrun which is odd but not launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273072/catkin-configuration-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

issue resolved .... I created three independent workspaces and sourced them and add to ros path.
Looking ok.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0